# How to open an activity on button click event?

Tags: android

i want to use 3 button to my main activity . I have the code below .Toast are working are fine but when want to switch next activity then app crashes and i get a message that **"APP STOP WORKING"** where i am wrong plz help me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);


        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Categories.class);
            startActivity(intent);          
            break;
      case R.id.button2:
          Toast.makeText(this, "button2 is working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;

      case R.id.button3:
          Toast.makeText(this, "button3 is working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: try this `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Categories.class);` & provide us your error

Comment: post your manifest file here.

Comment: Please show your `Categories` activity

Answer (score 1):

Need to pass `Activity` `Contex` in `Intent`.

i.e. `this` replace with `MainActivity.this`.

Make sure you have declared your **Categories activity** in `Android manifest` file.

Answer (score 0):

It would be really helpful if you can post the logs that are displayed when  the crash has occurred. I guess you might have forgotten to add your activity in the manifest file.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Categories">
 </activity>
```

Add the above lines and see if the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, you might be missing activity(Categories activity) declaration in AndroidManifest Or you might need to revisit your new activity (categories activity in your case) on create() for possible flaws. Logs will help us to point to the problem.

Comment: You should upvote the answers you think might be instead of posting again the same thing.